# Android Studio 2.3.3 issue where the virtual phone UI appears in the top left of the virtual phone, but functions correctly

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Hey, this is an example of the issue I'm having with Android Studio. I dont think I have made any changes from my first few programs which worked fine and the UI filled the whole Emulator screen

This is the 4th ever app I've written for a web dev class with android studio. I have written 3 other apps that did not have this issue with the phone. But after starting up android studio today to work on the next project for a class the issue in the picture would take place. The Virtual phone works properly but just has a very badly sized image instead of the full virtual phone screen.

I've sent a copy of the program I've been working on to my professor, but haven't heard back yet. Ive also tried to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio but the issue still remains. If anyone can give me a few hints or help in resizing the image to the correct size in the Emulator it would be much appreciated. Thank you very much.